# Nilpotent elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})[x_1,...,x_m]/\langle f_1(x_1,...,x_m),f_2(x_1,...,x_m),...f_k(x_1,...,x_m)\rangle$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

This is generalization of the [univariate case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461192/nilpotent-elements-of-k-mathbbz-n-mathbbzx-fx)
and also related to [open problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364267/rings-or-algebras-with-many-nilpotent-elements-and-efficient-computation).

Let $n,k,m,B>1$ be positive integers and $f_1(x_1,...,x_m),f_2(x_1,...,x_m),...f_k(x_1,...,x_m)$ be polynomials with integer coefficients.

Let $K=(\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})[x_1,...,x_m]/\langle f_1(x_1,...,x_m),f_2(x_1,...,x_m),...f_k(x_1,...,x_m)\rangle$.

Let $S$ be the set of degree 2 nilpotent elements of $K$ of degree at
most $B$:

$$S=\{g : g \in K, g^2=0,\deg(g) \le B \}$$

I am trying to find large subset of $S'$ of $S$ such that
$\prod S' \ne 0$.

> Q1 How large can $S'$ be?

Lower bound for $|S'|$ is $m+1$ by setting $k=m$ and $n=n_0^2$
and $f_i=x_i^2$ and $S'=\{n_0,x_1,x_2,...x_m\}$.

Disadvantage of this construction is that working in this quotient
is not efficient because of exponential growth of monomials.