# On the multiplicative group of quotients of polynomial rings

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, factorization

Related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461252/nilpotent-elements-of-mathbbz-n-mathbbzx-1-x-m-langle-f-1x-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The $p+1$ [factorization algorithm](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eyuvalf/Factorization.pdf) works over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[x]/f(x)$
and hopes $p+1$ to be smooth.

We are trying to generalize this to multivariate case
and also try to find nilpotent elements.

Let $p$ be prime and $k,m$ be positive integers and $f_1(x_1,...,x_m),f_2(x_1,...,x_m),...f_k(x_1,...,x_m)$ be polynomials with integer coefficients.

Let $K=\mathbb{F}_p[x_1,...,x_m]/\langle f_1(x_1,...,x_m),f_2(x_1,...,x_m),...f_k(x_1,...,x_m)\rangle$.

Let $K^*$ be the multiplicative group of $K$ and
let $\rho=|K^*|$. $\rho$ can be zero positive integer of infinity.

> Q1 Is there simple closed form for $\rho$?

For $a \in K^*$, if $a^r$ is of bounded degree (which
happens experimentally) then $a^r$ will become periodic.

> Q2 for $p=5$ and $a$ given by the following sage code, is $a$ of finite order?

[sagemath.org online](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNj8EKwyAQRO-C_-BRtzbETdpLao_twU8ICeTQQiC0Fiz4-dVsJIVFHjPDzurtqXPVJdY6Gh3xau836VU_cOY-37d1VXrD_HgF2bcQa4g4ojiIxGaFhkQik0iLLJCJOd5QPIsk7fkUzs6I5G3rB8XZZHO9LC5uriHEtWDnchWW4vZfUfQXzoJd5meQE4D0eeB8NAoAlerCDx_KQes=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
p=5;K.<x0,x1,x2>=GF(p)[]
Kquo=K.quotient([4*x0*x2^2 + 4*x1^2 + 3*x0*x2 + 3*x1*x2, x0*x1^2 + 2*x2^3 + 4*x0*x1 + 2*x0*x2 + 3*x2, 4*x0^2*x1 + x0*x2^2])
a=Kquo(4*x0^2*x2 + x0*x1*x2 + 2*x1^2*x2 + 2*x1*x2^2 + 2*x1^2 + 4*x2^2 + 2*x1)
Kquo
t=lift(a**(p*(p**6-1)**2));t
```